# How do I bind an Android ContentProvider to a series of TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contentprovider

I have an Android `ContentProvider` that dynamically updates on a different thread. How do I bind it to a series of `TextView`?

Reading the examples on Android Developers, I only managed to find out how to get it work for a ListView. However, I also need to bind a single row of the data to some text fields.

How should I do that?

Comment: In the same way... Instead swapping cursor - iterate it and set text fields from it's data

Comment: How do I do that? I implemented `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` when I worked with ListView, then used a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: see Cursor#move*() and Cursor#get*() methods

Comment: @pskink Would the text view update if data from the ContentProvider update?

Comment: sure, but you need to `registerContentObserver` (Uri uri, boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)